# Hide and Show Input Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

When running this solution to hide and show an input mask, on page load I am seeing both input boxes. My script has been placed on the bottom of the page as last script. I am basically hiding and showing one or the other input box based on the checkbox. All appears to be working perfectly on jsfiddle and this code snippet, yet on Chrome, Android browser, Firefox and Safari both input boxes display on page load. After I toggle the checkbox, then it works properly. Not sure what is causing it to show both input boxes on page load. Any help wold be appreciated.

```js
var showPass=false;
$('#c').change(function(){
    showPass = ($('#c:checked').length>0);
    if (showPass){
        $('#p').hide();
        $('#transaction_id').show();
    }else{
        $('#transaction_id').hide();
        $('#p').show();
    }
});

$('#p').change(function(){
    if (!showPass) $('#transaction_id').val($('#p').val());
});
$('#transaction_id').change(function(){
    if (showPass) $('#p').val($('#transaction_id').val());
});
```

```css
#transaction_id{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

<div class="bs-example">
<form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="form2" name="form2" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input">Scan Receipt, ID or </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c">
<span class="phonenum">Phone Number</span>
<div class="input-group">
  
  
  <input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="p" class="form-control" placeholder="receipt or ID" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="transaction_id" class="form-control" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" style="display:none" autofocus />
<input type="hidden" id="activity_id" name="activity_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['recordID']; ?>" />
                                 
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="this.disabled = true;
                                                    this.value = 'Saving...';
                                                    this.form.submit();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Redeem Ticket</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I found the solution. Just needed to initially hide the 2nd input:

```
<input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="transaction_id" class="form-control" 
placeholder="(999) 999-9999" style="display:none" autofocus />
```

Simple solution. I have also fixed the code snippet for anyone who wants to use it.